# How to create a Proxy for an Array in TypeScript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, proxy

I am trying to use a Proxy to add logic whenever a value in my array gets set to a new value. However, TypeScript is complaining because it doesn't like that the array gets indexed with something that isn't a number.

```
const nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const handler: ProxyHandler<number[]> = {
  set(target: number[], property: string | symbol, newValue: any) {
    target[property] = newValue;
    return true;
  },
};

const proxy = new Proxy(nums, handler);
```

On the line with `target[property] = newValue;` I get the error `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.ts(7015)`.

Is there a good way to make TypeScript happy?

Answer (score 0):

Do you index arrays with `string`? No, you generally index them with `number`, and that's what TS tells you.

```
const nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const handler: ProxyHandler<number[]> = {
  set(target: number[], property: string | symbol | number, newValue: any) {
    if (typeof property !== 'number') throw new Error('You can only index array with `number`!')
    target[property] = newValue;
    return true;
  },
};

const proxy = new Proxy(nums, handler);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBGCuBbCMC8MDaBGANDATHgMx4AseArALoDcAUHaJLABYCGYAJgDYCmATgC4YABX4gAHgE8AEhx4CAPAkQAjARioA+NDADedGDAi8oACiht+Ac1PCV6-prwAHcS4FQpw6PwCWYNYwAD7GUmog3CFwSI54YLwA7gBqbNzwvMIcUgCU+oZGMH4AZjAWUh4gpW4gHvxeMACEqOgA5A4CrXlQLOKJcEkwAKL84vxmrQCaIPAwwBww4NxSRVy8EjBW-GwriX49MAAGHfyHjV0FRpY2phg1dV5UugkpaRn0hTD8pvD8YDBQfjvAoAXxwdBB9EY4GgMBq0megzEkikZhUEDw7C4fH4ORoQA)

Comment: Then you can't do `proxy.somethingElse = ...`. I suppose TypeScript wouldn't allow it anyways, but it makes the runtime work differently.